# Correlation of the positions of a multidimensional array to what they represent during initialization

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, dimensions

I first want to clarify if my logic in the following is correct:
 In a 2 dimensional array, say A[x][y], x represents the number of braces and y the number of elements in each brace. So int A[2][3] is initialized as:

```
{
{1,2,3}, //from A[0][0] to A[0][2];
{4,5,6} //from A[1]{0] to A[1][2];
};
```

Second, I want to know what the similar correlations are in a 3 dimensional array, four dimensional, and so on, and how to know which dimension number correlates to what level for any multi-dimensional array.
For example, in A[3][4][2], does the 3 denote the number of 2d tables, or rows/columns in each table? And in A[2][3][4][5], does 2 represent the number of 2d tables, no. of 3d tables, no. of 1d tables, or no. of rows/columns per 1d table? Note:I'm getting my head around multi dimensional arrays for the first time, please explain as simplistically as possible.

Comment: You example above is correct, and the extrapolation to 3D, etc.. will work although they become more abstract with each extra dimension. So a 3D array is an array of 2D arrays, etc.. Also make sure you are familiar with *pointer* notation for array indexes, e.g. `A[x][y] = *(*(A + y) + x)`. (interesting last name for a handle `:)`

Comment: I'm aware of that, I just want to know what dimension number correlates to what during initialization. I've edited in an example to clarify.

Comment: Ok, I'll leave your edit to you as you add to your question, but please format inline code between `\'\'` backticks. That's were the abstraction becomes a head-game. Take 3D, thats a new dimension to make an array of 2D arrays so `A[2][2][3]` would be 2 of your example above in an extra set of `{}`.

Comment: The rules for initialiser lists can be a bit strange... the inner brackets don't have to match the number of array dimensions.  eg. `int a[2][3] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};` will do the same thing as `int a[2][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};`.  However: `int a[2][3] = {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}}` does the same as `int a[2][3] = {{1,2,0},{3,4,0}};` and discards the `{5,6}` because there isn't a 3rd element in the outer array, and similarly `int a[2][3] = {{1,2,3,4,5,6}};` does the same as `int a[2][3] = {{1,2,3},{0,0,0}};`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes what you say it's correct. You can think that ***recursively***.

Start from a 1D array (let's assume that it has 3 elements):

```
int 1darray[] = {0, 1, 2};
```

---

Now producing a 2D array simply says go inside every element of `1darray` and put another 1D array, to produce a 2D one, like this:

```
int 2darray[] = {1darray_0, 1darray_1, 1darray_2};
```

where the `1darray_0`, `1darray_1`, `1darray_2` are 1D arrays, just like the `1darray` we created in the start. So now this will form a 3x3 2D array.

---

Now the 3D array can be formed like this:

```
int 3darray[] = {2darray_0, 2darray_1, 2darray_2};
```

where the `2darray_0`, `2darray_1`, `2darray_2` are 2D arrays, just like the `2darray` we created above. So now this will form a 3x3x3 3D array.

---

Your example:

```
A[3][4][2]
```

says that `A` has:

1. 3 rows
2. 4 columns
3. 2 z-columns

---

In general however, I would advice you to have in mind the picture I have in my [2D dynamic array (C)](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/2d-dynamic-array-c/):

[image]

which describes in a nutshell what I tried to explain in the start.

As you increase your dimensions, you replace every element of the previous array with an array of the next dimension, while you reach the end.